# Could the Tags tab in the profile page also count in questions?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'm more an asker than an answerer, so for me the Tags tab, and my top tag is far from representative of my most active tag.

[image]

Yes AC-Revelations is my most answered tag (with 21 posts/80 score), but my most active tag is breath of the wild, with 45 posts, but 0 score because I only have 2 answers that are 0 score. I have 43 questions with 178 score.

So why is Question score not counted in the tags tab (and for the top tag?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main reason is because of how [Tag Badges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges) work (see the Tag Badge section in the link).  Tag Badges only count how many [non-wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) answers you post, and how many votes you earn on those answers.  It is also how this tab sorts your tags (by total number of up votes minus down votes on your answers for the badge).

As for why questions don't count, well, tag badges are to show how knowledgeable you are for that tag.  Asking questions doesn't really represent your knowledge on a topic (in fact, you could argue it shows the opposite - no offense intended, it's why the site exists)!

If you hover over the number to the left of the tag, a tool tip will show up with some information.  This below screenshot is for your [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag:

[image: Tool tip]

Note that the number to the right of the tag is the total number of posts (both questions and answers), so if you want to know how many answers you have per tag, you will have to hover over the left number and read the tooltip (or if the tag is trackable, you can see your progress through there).

Comment: The 'non-wiki' must mean answers that are not on your own questions. But it still annoys me that this page is not representative of my most active tags because I ask more questions than I answer.

Comment: So the big difference is I thought it was 'Most Active', but in fact its 'More knowledgable'. Wonder if it could be done that you can switch between both ways? Because for an asker, this tab is not useful.

Comment: I don't think non-wiki means your own answers.  I'm not sure if they are counted or not.  But I do know it means when you select the check box for posting a community answer in the bottom right.

Comment: We should look at what is defined as wiki to understand. I remember seeing wiki somewhere, but cant remember

Comment: @Fredy31 [See this Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). I also put this link in my answer.  Some more info [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

Comment: @Fredy31 & @ Timmy - all posts (questions or answers) can be marked as 'community wiki'. The idea is the post gets edited by the whole community, for example, maybe it's a lengthy guide of occasionally changing mechanics that requires semi-frequent updates. Posts marked community wiki are therefore not really 'owned' by the asker/answerer and therefore they don't earn rep from upvotes and why it's not counted in the tag score - after all. If 20 people have edited your answer to be up to date, is it really still 'your' answer?

Comment: @Robotnik do you know if answering your own question counts towards tag badges?

Comment: @TimmyJim - Yes it does, so long as it's not marked community wiki. Take my answers in [controllers](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A28182+%5Bcontrollers%5D+is%3Aa) for example. One answer is a self answer worth 4 (which counts), and another answer is community wiki worth 1 (which doesn't count). The answer scores add up to 18, but I have 17 tag score.